# no bootable os found: ubuntu 18.04lts . clean installation /root /home /boot /data /swap

Tags: partitioning

i have my laptop installed using "something else" option on ubuntu 18.04lts. 
it was a clean and successful installation on  /root /home /boot /data /swap partition

upon restart with boot usb stick unplugged: no bootable os found:

where went wrong ?  [image]

sdf is the disk. (i have plugged the disk into my current computer on usb. it is a standard rotating 1tb hdd) i plugged it into this computer to check on gparted or other software to analyse the problem.

[image]

Comment: `/boot` can't be on fat32. That is crap. And tere is no `/` parttion. Total crap.

Comment: boot can't be on fat32 ? i thought fat32 is the best format that every os on earth can use !!

Comment: oh, maybe i have screw that one up. it was like this (before i changed it to a properly named names):

Comment: it was like this:  sdf1 /boot , sdf2 / , sdf3 /swap , sdf4 /home , sdf5 /data

Comment: i apparently gone nut with gparted to make the names sound better when i moved the hdd to my pc for analysing.. the sdf 1 2 3 4 5 confused me, hence i thought make it a proper name that i can understand which partition is what.. lol hence this happened. but before this it was proper name as i stated above. which the laptop said no bootable os found.

Comment: i have to change it back .lol  crap...